# Are there shouts/words for shouts that are missable?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What I mean by missable is, if you miss it the first time you go to the dungeon or location you cannot get it at latter time by revisiting it.

According to

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/191475-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-special-edition/74676451

Only one, namely storm call, is missable, and that's when you visit sovngrade/heaven or something. Is there another one?

I just revisited Saarthal. I no longer have the amulet and I've heard people having trouble. Yet, I went through the dungeon just fine with no issue at all and got my word wall.

Anything I should watch out so I do not miss any words?

Missable here means you have one, or limited chance to get the word. After that you can't revisit the dungeon to look for it.

Answer (score 4):

The Word Wall in High Gate Ruins in Hjaalmarch is missable. The wall lies through two gates which can be opened after killing Vokun. However, if you kill Vokun, exit the dungeon through them but miss the wall, the gates will shut and you will not be able to enter that part of the dungeon again if entering coastside. This is a bug, as stated [here](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:High_Gate_Ruins#Bugs), and is fixed in the Unofficial Skyrim Patch.

There is another Word Wall near Bard's Leap Summit: it's out in the open so you can revisit it, but it's hidden and very easy to walk past, so you may well 'miss' it in the traditional way.